# Laravel - Ter uma função unica de criação da entidade

Tags: php, laravel

Depois de ver muito na internet, entendi que não devo chamar uma função de um controlador em outro e que a solução mas elegante é criar um service, porem não entendi como crio o service e muito menos como chamo as funções dele.

O que eu preciso fazer é que ao criar uma simulado, eu crie uma proposta e vincule a esse simulado, porem já tenho um lugar que crio essa proposta, no contralador dela:

```
public function create(Request $proposta)
    {
        $this->valida($proposta);
        $uuid = Str::uuid();

        //load file
        $file = $proposta->file('file');

        // s3 storage
        Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs(
            'proposta/',
            $file,
            $uuid . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
            [
                'visibility' => 'public',
                'mimetype' => 'application/pdf'
            ]
        );

        //get sotarege url
        $url = ('https://meuprovedor/proposta/' . $uuid . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());

        $prop = Proposta::create([
            'nome' => $proposta['nome'],
            'numero' => $proposta['numero'],
            'url' => $url,
            'escola_id' => $proposta['escola_id'],
            'grade_id' => $proposta['grade_id'],
        ]);

//        Log::error(print_r($proposta['videos'],true));
//        Log::error(print_r(json_decode($proposta['videos']),true));

        foreach (json_decode($proposta['videos']) as $video) {
            Video::create([
                'ordem' => $video->ordem,
                'titulo' => $video->titulo,
                'video_url' => $video->video_url,
                'proposta_id' => $prop->id
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json("Prosposta Criada", 200);
    }
```

Agora na minha função que cria o meu simulado preciso criar uma proposta passando o meu request e pegar o id da proposta criada para passar pra criação do simulado (ali na parte comentada):

```
 public function create(Request $simulado)
    {
        $this->valida($simulado);

        $pieces = explode('T', $simulado->data);

        return new SimuladoResource(Simulado::create([
            'data' => Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $pieces[0]),

            'escola_id' => $simulado['escola_id'],
            'proposta_id' => //função que cria uma proposta e retorna o id,
        ]));
    }
```

minha duvida é: Existe um comando php artisan pra criar esse service? Eu só crio ele e ai crio uma função la dentro e importando o arquivo nos meus controladores ja consigo chamar a função? Pergunto isso porque nas referencias do laravel, fala pra criar um interface, register e mais um monte de coisa, não entendi o que tenho que fazer pra ter uma função unica que tando o create da proposta usa, quando o create do simulado use.

Comment: Service que dizem é uma classe qualquer que executa alguma lógica. Há quem abuse do uso de Service por preguiça de nomear corretamente aquela lógica. De certa forma, você já está usando um "service" dentro do seu controller com o método $this->valida(), a diferença é que isso ficaria numa classe separada, a grosso modo. Mover esse método valida para um Form Request do Laravel, por exemplo, seria o mais próximo que posso pensar como analogia para um service.

Comment: No mais, tente organizar melhor os passos para criar sua entidade. o que eles tem em comum é a lógica para fazer um upload para o S3? Extraia e nomeie isso para reutilizar em outro lugar se fizer sentido.

Comment: Se puder postar também as referencias que você consultou, também ajuda para entender como você imaginou resolver esse problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que eu imagino é que você pode ter se confundido com a idéia de Service, Service Container e Service Provider. Independente de ser ou não, sem entrar muito em detalhes profundos, mas nos suficientes:

O que você pode fazer é criar uma classe para encapsular esta lógica e invocar no Controller que você precisa. 
Não existe comando para criar essa classe, o jeito de contruí-la é manualmente, da forma como você já conhece: um arquivo para uma classe, nomeado com nome da classe. Não se esqueça do namespace!
Sim, na realidade procure encapsular ao máximo suas lógicas de négocio, retirando o que puder do controller. Quando criar sua classe de serviço, ela deverá funcionar no "Service Container" do Laravel que usa Inversão de Controle e Injeção de dependência. O service container é uma classe que cria um objeto para criar outros objetos. Você também deve ter perguntando sobre comando do artisan para "criar service" porque tem pesquisado sobre os "service providers" e acreditando que estes eram as classes de service.

Na realidade, os service providers são meios de ensinar o service container, a maneira como ele deverá instanciar um objeto de serviço. Você não irá implementar sua lógica na classe de Service Provider, mas irá usá-la para registrar seu service e/ou manipulá-lo. [ Ou seja, aquela classe que você criou manualmente antes e implementou os métodos que precisava, com sua lógica de negócio encapsulada. ]

Por exemplo, no caso de um registro de service funcional: suponhamos que você tenha criado sua classe Service para fazer simulado, chamada "SimuladoService". Daí você quer usar alguns métodos dessa classe dentro do seu controller, talvez até um método chamado create(). Mas aí você pensa, eu preciso passar parâmetros na criação desse service, como fazer? Suponhamos que você criasse um service provider do Laravel para ensinar o service container a instanciar SimuladoService, usando o comando no terminal:

```
php artisan make:provider SimuladoServiceProvider
```

Então, esta classe que foi gerada, viria com dois métodos default: register e boot. Você deveria usar o register() para registrar sua classe de service, por exemplo, desta maneira:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(SimuladoService::class, function($app, array $parameters) {
        return new SimuladoService($parameters[0], $parameters[1], $parameters[2]);
    });
}
```

Cada índice no array parameters, corresponderá um dos parâmetros sendo passados para SimuladoService. Daí é só você ir lá no seu controller e chamar esse serviço usando o helper app:

```
$service = app()->make(SimuladoService::class, [$parametro1, $parametro2, $parametro3]);
$service->create($parametro);
```

Claro, que tudo isso irá funcionar depois de registrar o seu novo service provider no arquivo config/app.php. Obviamente, os parâmetro são fictícios em relação a sua implementação. Mas acredito que você deve ter entendido a idéia!

Esta é uma maneira de usar services que você criou, usando o service container do Laravel. Quando você tiver prática, eles vão ficar bem elegantes.

[]'s